# aggrid how to have if condition in the field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ag-grid

I want to add an if condition in the aggrid col def

```
this.ColumnDefs =
      [
        {

          headerName: "Link Text", field: "portfolioCompanyLinkName.name", editable: false
        },
}
```

so in the above example can we somehow say if portfolioCompanyLinkName.name is empty then take value from other column?

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: @NoahLc So basically i actually want to say something like if the portfolioCompanyLinkName.name value is empty then take value from linkname
So something like portfolioCompanyLinkName.name==''?linkName:portfolioCompanyLinkName.name

Comment: portfolioCompanyLinkName is it an object?

Comment: @NoahLc yes its an object

Comment: You need just to write field: portfolioCompanyLinkName.name ? portfolioCompanyLinkName.name : portfolioCompanyLinkName
if it's an object you should write it without "

Comment: if it's worked with you tell me to put it like an answer

Comment: @NoahLc I actually tried that but it doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204414/discussion-between-noah-lc-and-ashish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use valueGetter you can full detailed here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Link Text",
    valueGetter: function(params) {
    if(params.data.portfolioCompanyLinkName.name !== undefined) {
        return params.data.name;
    } else {
        return params.data.portfolioCompanyLinkName.otherfield;
    }

    }
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
this.ColumnDefs =
      [
        {
          headerName: "Link Text", 
          field: "portfolioCompanyLinkName.name", 
          editable: false,
          cellRenderer: function (params) {
          return params.data ? params.data.portfolioCompanyLinkName.name ? params.data.portfolioCompanyLinkName.name :   params.data.(other field) : '';
        }
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `hide` and `suppressToolPanel` properties and make them true to hide and to show.

To Hide:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
       headerName: "Stone_ID",
       field: "Stone_ID",
       width: 100,
       hide: true,
       suppressToolPanel: true
    }
]
```

To Show:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
       headerName: "Stone_ID",
       field: "Stone_ID",
       width: 100,
       hide: false,
       suppressToolPanel: true
    }
]
```